# Can Polymer extend Electron's webview component?

Tags: polymer, electron

In Electron (Atom-Shell), I'm trying to use Polymer 0.5 to extend Electron's [webview tag](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-view-tag.md) (to add some custom attributes while retaining all of webview's methods). But I'm getting a NotSupportedError when I try to use my custom component. Is there a way to make this work?

Here's how I'm extending the webview:

```
<polymer-element name="my-webview" extends="webview">
    <script>
        Polymer({
            // I'll add some custom attributes later
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

But when I try to use my-webview (either of these ways):

```
<my-webview src="http://example.com"></my-webview>
<webview is="my-webview" src="http://example.com"></webview>
```

...I get this error:

> Uncaught NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'registerElement' on
>   'Document': Registration failed for type 'my-webview'. The tag name
>   specified in 'extends' is a custom element name. Use inheritance
>   instead.

Now, it's true that Electron's [webview is indeed a custom element](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/v0.25.2/atom/renderer/lib/web-view/web-view.coffee#L208-L210). But Polymer happily extends other custom elements, right?

It seems like one problem might be that "webview" doesn't have a '-' in its name, so Polymer's [`findTypeExtension`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/0.5.x/src/declaration/prototype.js#L203-L212) doesn't realize it's a custom element.

Is there any way to work around this and convince Polymer that webview needs to be extended through inheritance, like other custom elements?

Comment: For future readers, looking at the webview's shadow-root,  you see that the webview is treated as a browser plugin. This would explain why the webview element has a lot of funky behavior, because, under the covers, it is not even an HTML element at all, but instead is a special kind of chromium plug-in.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, you refered to the webview as "Electron's webview tag". But if we were to get technical, it is not an Electron element — its a chromium element.  If you want to learn more about it: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview

Comment: Oh, interesting. Thanks for the link. So, as far as Polymer can tell, webview is a native tag. Except, it's not really, under the hood. (I'll google around to see if this has come up in the Chromium/Chrome App context.)